# Is there a way to combine Archivable and Versionable behaviours in Propel 1?

Tags: php, propel, behavior

I'm using Propel 1 in a fairly sizeable project, and the live version presently uses the `Archivable` behaviour. Thus, when a row is deleted, the behaviour transparently intercepts the call and moves the row into an archive table. This works fine.

I'm looking to change how this table works so that all saves are versioned. On a feature branch I have therefore removed the `Archivable` and added the `Versionable` behaviour. This drops the `(table)_archive` auto-generated table and adds a `(table)_version` table instead.

However, interestingly, the version table has a PK of `(id, version)` with a foreign key to the live table from `id` to `id`. This means that versions cannot exist without a live row, which is not what I want: I want to be able to delete a row and preserve the versions.

I thought this behaviour would act like `Archivable` i.e. the `delete()` method would be intercepted and modified from its usual approach. Unfortunately, as confirmed by [the documentation](http://propelorm.org/Propel/behaviors/versionable#public-api), this method deletes the live row *and* any prior versions:

> `void delete()`: Deletes the object version history

I tried mixing both `Archivable` and `Versionable`, but this seems to generate code that crashes in the `Query` API: it tries to call an `archive()` method that does not exist. I expect this behaviour mix was never intended to work (ideally it should be caught at schema build-time, and perhaps that will be fixed in Propel 2).

One solution is to try the `SoftDelete` behaviour instead of `Archivable` - this just marks records as deleted rather than moving them to another table. However this can be problematic because joining to a table with this behaviour can give the wrong counts for non-deleted rows (and the Propel team decided to deprecate it for this reason). It also feels like a rabbit-hole I don't want to go down, since the amount of refactoring may spiral out of control.

Thus, I am left with seeking a better approach to implement a versioning system that does not delete old versions when the live copy is deleted. I can do this manually by intercepting save and delete methods in the model class, but it seems a waste when `Versionable` nearly does what I want. Are there relevant parameters I can tweak, or is there value in writing a custom behaviour? A quick look at the template generation code for core behaviours makes me want to run away from the latter!

Comment: Hi. Would you mind to share your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. My memory is rather hazy but it looks like I've taken the existing `VersionableBehaviour` and derived from it a new behaviour, which I have called `HistoryVersionableBehaviour`. It thus uses all the features of the core behaviour and then just overrides the generated delete with its own code.

Here is the behaviour itself:

```
<?php

// This is how the versionable behaviour works
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/HistoryVersionableBehaviorObjectBuilderModifier.php';

class HistoryVersionableBehavior extends VersionableBehavior
{
    /**
     * Reset the FKs from CASCADE ON DELETE to no action
     * 
     * (I expect all future migration diffs will incorrectly try to re-add the constraint
     * I manually removed from the migration that introduced versioning, may try to fix
     * that another time. 'Tis fine for now).
     */
    public function addVersionTable()
    {
        parent::addVersionTable();

        $this->swapAllForeignKeysToNoDeleteAction();
        $this->addVersionArchivedColumn();
    }

    protected function swapAllForeignKeysToNoDeleteAction()
    {
        $versionTable = $this->lookupVersionTable();
        $fks = $versionTable->getForeignKeys();
        foreach ($fks as $fk)
        {
            $fk->setOnDelete(null);
        }
    }

    protected function addVersionArchivedColumn()
    {
        $versionTable = $this->lookupVersionTable();
        $versionTable->addColumn(array(
            'name' => 'archived_at',
            'type' => 'timestamp',
        ));
    }

    protected function lookupVersionTable()
    {
        $table = $this->getTable();
        $versionTableName = $this->getParameter('version_table') ?
            $this->getParameter('version_table') :
            ($table->getName() . '_version');
        $database = $table->getDatabase();

        return $database->getTable($versionTableName);
    }

    /**
     * Point to the custom object builder class
     * 
     * @return HistoryVersionableBehaviorObjectBuilderModifier
     */
    public function getObjectBuilderModifier()
    {
        if (is_null($this->objectBuilderModifier)) {
            $this->objectBuilderModifier = new HistoryVersionableBehaviorObjectBuilderModifier($this);
        }

        return $this->objectBuilderModifier;
    }
}
```

This needs something called a modifier, which is run at generation time to produce the base instance classes:

```
<?php

class HistoryVersionableBehaviorObjectBuilderModifier extends \VersionableBehaviorObjectBuilderModifier
{
    /**
     * Don't do any version deletion after the main deletion
     * 
     * @param \PHP5ObjectBuilder $builder
     */
    public function postDelete(\PHP5ObjectBuilder $builder)
    {
        $this->builder = $builder;
        $script = "// Look up the latest version
\$latestVersion = {$this->getVersionQueryClassName()}::create()->
    filterBy{$this->table->getPhpName()}(\$this)->
    orderByVersion(\Criteria::DESC)->
    findOne(\$con);
\$latestVersion->
    setArchivedAt(time())->
    save(\$con);
        ";

        return $script;
    }
}
```

The parent class has 798 lines, so my approach does seem to have saved a great deal of code, over building it all from scratch!

You'll need to specify the behaviour in your XML file for each table you want to activate it for:

```
<table name="job">
    <!--- your columns... -->
    <behavior name="timestampable" />
    <behavior name="history_versionable" />
</table>
```

I am not sure whether my behaviour requires the presence of the `timestampable` behaviour - my guess is no, since it looks like the parent behaviour just adds columns to the versioned table and not the table itself. If you are able to try this without the `timestampable` behaviour do let me know how you get on, so I can update this post.

Finally you'll need to specify the location of your class so the Propel 1 custom autoloader knows where to find it. I use this in my `build.properties`:

```
# Declare a custom behaviour
propel.behavior.history_versionable.class = ${propel.php.dir}.WebScraper.Behaviours.HistoryVersionable.HistoryVersionableBehavior
```